# Filter is getting cleared after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented multiselect filter like this 
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#animations

However after refresh it is holding the value(because filtered records are showing in UI) but the multiselect checkbox is getting cleared. Can you please suggest me how to bring back the selected value in the UI after refresh?

This is my code to retain the value from cookie after refresh

```
searchString = cookievalue.trim();
                searchString = searchString.replace(/%20/g,' ');
                searchString = searchString.replace(/%7C/g, '|');
                //searchString = searchString.replace(/%27/g, "'");
                if (searchString.indexOf(ws1) >= 0){
                    //j$('#first').prop('checked') = true;
                    document.getElementById('aa').checked = true;
                } 
                if (searchString.indexOf(ws2) >= 0){
                    document.getElementById('bb').checked = true;
                }        
                oTable.fnFilter(searchString,18,true,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite broad (if I'm not misunderstood) There are some alternative..

1. save it to the database (using any server side programming language), then when the page visited, generate the the `select` with `selected='selected'` on each previously saved `option`
2. save it to the [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and when the `onload`, restore the selection using `javascript`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the suggestion, I am doing the samething,         searchString = cookievalue.trim();
    searchString = searchString.replace(/%20/g,' ');
    searchString = searchString.replace(/%7C/g, '|');
    //searchString = searchString.replace(/%27/g, "'");
    if (searchString.indexOf(ws1) >= 0){
     //j$('#first').prop('checked') = true;
     document.getElementById('aa').checked = true;
    } 
    if (searchString.indexOf(ws2) >= 0){
     document.getElementById('bb').checked = true;
    }        
    oTable.fnFilter(searchString,18,true,false);  Still its getting cleared after refresh

Comment: post a full code, so we could reproduce and find the error